# Connecting Bluemix DB2 on Cloud (DashDB) to IBM BPMoC

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, dashdb, ibm-bpm

I'm trying to connect a database in the Bluemix DB2 on Cloud (DashDB) to IBM BPM on Cloud. Is this possible? I tried setting up a datasource in BPMoC using the data provided by DB2 on Cloud, but it is not able to connect:

> (Error Details)[jcc][t4][2043][11550][4.18.60] Exception
>   java.net.SocketException: Error opening socket to server ... with
>   message: Network is unreachable (connect failed). ERRORCODE=-4499,
>   SQLSTATE=08001 DSRA0010E: SQL State = 08001, Error Code = -4,499Test
>   Connection

Comment: There are 3 different Db2 / dashDB services on Bluemix. You should be able to connect to them. What did you configure?

Answer (score 0):

IBM BPM on Cloud support was able to help me get this working. There was something that needed to be done on the network side of things to allow BPMoC to talk with DB2 on Cloud (Bluemix). They also had to install the SSL certs for me.